# Spring MVC: What are the allowable default date formats?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring Web MVC application, I have a bunch of methods in `@Controller`s that accept a `Date` as an input parameter with `@RequestParam`. Without defining any custom data binders or property editors (I admit I'm still not clear on the difference between those two), what date formats are supported by default?  For example, I've noticed that something like '11/12/2012 16:50 PM' works fine, but a plain milis value like '1352815200000' is rejected.

Edit: the specific exception I get is: "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if no converter is specified, Spring convertion system will end up calling the  deprecated `Date` constructor, that takes String as an argument.

```
/**
 * Allocates a <code>Date</code> object and initializes it so that
 * it represents the date and time indicated by the string
 * <code>s</code>, which is interpreted as if by the
 * {@link Date#parse} method.
 *
 * @param   s   a string representation of the date.
 * @see     java.text.DateFormat
 * @see     java.util.Date#parse(java.lang.String)
 * @deprecated As of JDK version 1.1,
 * replaced by <code>DateFormat.parse(String s)</code>.
 */
@Deprecated
public Date(String s) {
    this(parse(s));
}
```

usually the applications have different requirements - some work with the local time(also browser specific things and user time zone settings may come into play), some don't need to store the date - so it's better to implement a policy for date conversion both on client and server side.

P.S. please note that `Date.parse()` is also deprecated.

Comment: I see. Of course, `Date` also has a constructor that takes a `long` - it would be nice if Spring could detect numeric input and know to use it. But whatever, I can implement that myself easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

The allowed date formats probably depend on your current Locale.

You can add a Handler that converts the date for the formats you like.

I'm not really sure which one was it. [*@InitBinder*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder) shows an example of converting a date from whatever format..

Comment: Can you elaborate? I control my server's locale I suppose, but shouldn't, at the very least, a Unix timestamp be universal?

Comment: @Dan I think it was the InitBinder. Check ResultBinding as well. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam Otherwise the petclinic might give further insight.

Comment: Yes, I've seen how to customize the `DataBinder`, but I still don't understand what the _default_ behavior is. It says "All simple types such as int, long, Date, etc. are supported." But what does that mean - what kind of Date formats are supported?

Answer (score 0):

hope this works for you.

Create a class Register an editor for your date formate.

```
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistry
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

public class CustomDateEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {

    String dateFormat = 'yyyy/MM/dd'
    registry.registerCustomEditor(Date, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat), true))
}
}
```