# spring mvc default date format for auto date conversion?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have employee data object which has date field DOB which user enters from UI. My question is *what is the 
default date format spring mvc expects so that its auto date conversion works or does its depend on locale info coming
from browser ?*

```
public class EmployeeData {
    private Date dob;
    ... getters and setters
}
```

I mean will spring auto date conversion will work for any of these date formats `"MM/dd/yyyy" or "dd/MM/yyyy" or "yyyyy/MM/dd"`

I know i can make use of CustomDateEditor but i am looking for what is the format spring accept for its default
date conversion.

Comment: Here is answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352196/spring-mvc-what-are-the-allowable-default-date-formats

Comment: i already had a look but thats not clear to me. As per answer looks like only date in format "Sat, 12 Aug 1995 13:30:00 GMT+0430" should work but not "11/12/2012 16:50 PM"(while OP says it works fine)

Comment: I think here is answer for your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705282/spring-mvc-binding-a-date-field

Comment: Yes "dd/MM/yyyy" is default supported as per this link as well - https://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/binding-date-in-spring/

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have observed in spring MVC which confirms [Spring MVC: What are the allowable default date formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352196/spring-mvc-what-are-the-allowable-default-date-formats). Spring by default resolves the date

```
    long autoConvertedDate= new Date().parse(strDate);
    System.out.println("date is " + new Date(autoConvertedDate));
```

where it expects strDate  in `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

If input date is  `"12/11/14"` result will be `11 Dec 2014`
If input date is  `"16/11/14"` result will be `11 Apr 2015`

Please note second pattern even if you input data is in `"16/11/14"` , Date object is considering
it in MM/dd/yyyy format where it has shifted year part to 2015 becoz input month is 16

Answer (score 0):

There is no default Date converter. Spring uses [ObjectToObjectConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/ObjectToObjectConverter.java) to convert String to Date.

> #### Conversion Algorithm

- Invoke a non-static `to[targetType.simpleName]()` method on the source object that has a return type equal to `targetType`, if such a method exists. For example, `org.example.Bar Foo#toBar()` is a method that follows this convention.
- Otherwise invoke a *static* `valueOf(sourceType)` or Java 8 style *static* `of(sourceType)` or `from(sourceType)` method on the `targetType`, if such a method exists.
- Otherwise invoke a constructor on the `targetType` that accepts a single `sourceType` argument, if such a constructor exists.
- Otherwise throw a `ConversionFailedException`.

Fortunately, `Date.java` has a *deprecated* constructor [public Date(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-java.lang.String-). By default, Spring call `new Date(String s)` to convert String to Date.